# Mono C# Set CultureInfo not working on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, mono, gettext, gtk#

I'm currently facing a bug, that the language of my application can not be set to something different than system default. I use the following Code to set the CultureInfo:

```
Catalog.Init("AudioCuesheetEditor", Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + MainClass.CONST_STR_LOCALE_PATH));
[...]
//Set the locale
log.debug("CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
if (Program.getInstance().getObjOption().getStrSelectedLanguage() != null)
{
    log.debug("Program.getInstance().getObjOption().getStrSelectedLanguage() = " + Program.getInstance().getObjOption().getStrSelectedLanguage());
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Program.getInstance().getObjOption().getStrSelectedLanguage());
    if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix)
    {
        //Mono Linux hack
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("LANGUAGE", Program.getInstance().getObjOption().getStrSelectedLanguage().Replace("-", "_"));
    }
}
Application.Init();
[...]
Application.Run();
```

This works perfect on linux, but doesn't work with gtk# on Windows. The CultureInfo is changed, but the language doesn't change. Any ideas why?

I get the string with Code like this:

```
Catalog.GetString("general ready")
```

I'm not shure, how to find the bug and what is wrong. Anybody who can help, thanks in advance ;).

Whole code can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/p/audiocuesheet/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/AudioCuesheetEditor/MainClass.cs

Sven

Comment: What does `Catalog.GetString` do? Can you produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? (As an aside, those method names look like you're writing C# with a distinct Java accent. Learn about properties and .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: IIRC `setenv()` is process-scoped, and of course `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` is thread-scoped. Could the strings be decided in another thread?

Comment: Catalog.GetString() is the standard way on Mono to get Strings that can be translated. More information can be found here: http://www.monodevelop.com/documentation/localizing-applications/

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I learned, that this is the standard way to set the CultureInfo in .NET (taken from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Nobody any idea? I'm a bit confused, why it is not working. Is this a bug of gtk# or mono?

Comment: Well-behaved .NET code pays attention to Thread.CurrentUICulture to decide which localization should be selected.  No real idea how well-behaved gtk# might be on Windows but as-is you don't give it chance to get it right.

Comment: I found out, that changing the environment variable "LANG" on windows works. So if I set "LANG=en" the application starts with english translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, that changing the environment variable "LANG" on windows works. So if I set "LANG=en" the application starts with english translation.

Answer (score 2):

Since internationalization is based on GNU gettext, my assuption would be that the windows implementation slightly differs form the unix one, so the `LANGUAGE` variable is read at startup before any of your code is executed. The only work around I can think of is to call your program with a script that sets the `LANGUAGE` variable.